# How to perform a non-linear regression pixel by pixel?

Tags: raster, r

Using nlsLM from Package ‘minpack.lm’ is straightforward for a simple example like this:

```
MODEL:y=(exp(a*x+b*z+c)+d)^f
x=c(0.5,0.3,0.2,0.4)
z=c(0.1,0.6,1,0.9)
y=c(0.2,0.3,0.9,0.9)
fit=nlsLM(y~(exp(a*x+b*z+c)+d)^f,start = list(a = -.03, b = 0.5, c = 1,d=0.02,f=0.003))
```

And no problem with that. My real data are multiple rasters for one year.So I have one year of data for x,y,z but as rasters that contain pixels,I want to do a non-linear regression pixel by pixel(each regression for one pixel is not related to the next pixel). example data:

```
   r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10); r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
   r1 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10);r1 <- setValues(r1, 1:ncell(r))
   r2 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10);r2 <- setValues(r1, 1:ncell(r))
st1=stack(r,r1,r2)

   rl <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10); r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
   rS <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10);r1 <- setValues(r1, 1:ncell(r))
   rT <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10);r2 <- setValues(r1, 1:ncell(r))
st2=stack(rl,rS,rT)

  re <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10); r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
  ru <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10);r1 <- setValues(r1, 1:ncell(r))
  rg <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10);r2 <- setValues(r1, 1:ncell(r))
st3=stack(re,ru,rg)
```

so first x would be the first pixel of st1(for the whole temporal period)

so first y would be the first pixel of st2(for the whole temporal period)

so first z would be the first pixel of st3(for the whole temporal period)

do regression for this pixel then do the same for all other pixels

As a result I get a map (raster) 10*10 for each best parameter(a,b,c,d,f)

I hope it is clear and you have any help!

Comment: There may be some underlying problems to resolve before doing any coding. In particular, you are trying to fit a five-parameter model to just four data points (or only three, in the case of the rasters!). Another issue--which won't go away even with more data--is that your model is not identifiable, because `exp(a*x+b*z+c)^d` is algebraically the same as `exp(d*a*x+d*b*z+d*c)`, which means only four of the five parameters can ever be determined.

Comment: Would the regression example at the bottom of [this page](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/calc) help?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment.The model is not important for the moment but the principle of doing non-linear regression for multiple rasters is the most important. So you can please use whatever model to show we can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want.

The model I have used is not the one you posted and it probably doesn't make any sense at all, however it does demonstrate the principle.

```
# Set up the rasters
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- r4 <- r5 <- r6 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10);
# Populate them with some values
r1 <- setValues(r1,runif(100,min=1,max=100));
r2 <- setValues(r2,runif(100,min=1,max=100));
r3 <- setValues(r3,runif(100,min=1,max=100));
r4 <- setValues(r4,runif(100,min=1,max=100));
r5 <- setValues(r5,runif(100,min=1,max=100));
r6 <- setValues(r6,runif(100,min=1,max=100));
# Stack them
st1 <- stack(r1,r2,r3);
st2 <- stack(r4,r5,r6);
# Set up the function
test <- function(r) {
    x <- r[1:3];
    y <- r[4:6];
    result <- c(NA,NA);
    try(result <- c(coef(nlsLM(y ~ a + b * x, start = list(a = 0.12345, b = 0.54321), na.action = na.omit))));
    result;
}
# Stack the stacks
s <- stack(st1,st2);
# Calculate a new Raster
rNLR <- calc(s, test);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I said my data are temporal for one year so `st1` has 365 rasters and `st2` has 365 rasters, etc...I wonder how we change this part `x <- r[1:3];
    y <- r[4:6]` ??

Comment: The model is not important but the way we do it is important.Thanks once again.

Comment: If you think of r as the pixel.  At that point you would have 365 layers twice in the stack.  So to put the pixel value into the vector x you specify it as x <- r[1~365]. Y is then set to the next 365 layer values in the stack.

Comment: so Y would be `y <- r[366~730]`?? what If I have another variable `z`, what would be `Z <- r[?~?]`

Comment: Yes we use `coef` instead of `fitted` and will get two layers for `a and b`but how we plot the outputs separately?

Comment: I apply this answer to my real data  but I got this error:`Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
  cannot use this function`

Comment: I have `NA` in my data so it causes that error.If  we can add something like this in the function:if there are at least three values in that pixel `x` with three corresponding values from `y`, do regression,else return NA for that pixel.Can you please modify your function.

Comment: @usersam, I have altered it.  I have used na.omit, but na.fail may do what you require.

Comment: Has anybody on this thread looked at help for the raster "calc" function, which provides an example for exactly this problem (see "some regression examples" at end of examples)? There are still tractability issues related to this approach that need to be considered so, yes the model does matter. In the temporal example that you indicate, you do not have a serial autocorrelation term in the model which, in a n=365 stack would certainly represent a pseudo-replication issue.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans, Yes.  I provided a link in my comment to the question.

Comment: If `r1[1]=NA; r3[1]=NA;r2[1]=NA` the function will fail. you may rethink your function.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans shuc as what you mean by a pseudo-replication issue?

Comment: To be honest, I wasn't trying to help with the actual model, rather the way to apply it to the raster.